# How to get the Names of all Columns in a Linq to Entity Datamodel (with one table)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have an Entity which is basically one Datamodel.

That Model has several "Columns"

```
ID, names, addresses, zip codes
```

All these columns are populated with data.

To "connect" to my entity framework, I'm using

```
using ( EntityFrameworkEntity entites = new EntityFrameworkEntity() ) 
{

}
```

So how can I get the names of these Columns now in a String array?

The Result should look like :

```
StringArray[0] = "ID"
StringArray[1] = "names"
StringArray[2] = "addresses" 
.
.
.
```

Any Help will be highly appreciated as I'm a beginner

Comment: So what you want to do, is to list the names of the columns in a  specific table?

Comment: May i ask why you want this? - What is it you are hoping to do with the string array?

Comment: I want to get those names to initalize dynamically some Form Elements for my website. Am I going the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
IEnumerable<FieldList> properties = from p in typeof(T).GetProperties()
                                where (from a in p.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                                where a is EdmScalarPropertyAttribute
                                select true).FirstOrDefault()
                                select new FieldList
                                {
                                   FieldName = p.Name,
                                   FieldType = p.PropertyType,
                                   FieldPK = p.GetCustomAttributes(false).Where(a => a is EdmScalarPropertyAttribute && ((EdmScalarPropertyAttribute)a).EntityKeyProperty).Count() > 0
                                 };
```

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'EdmScalarPropertyAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: @Evils check this linq http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/fdf336ff-ff45-496e-8805-f949b678db21